# removing locale prefix in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want NOT to show locale prefix in URL when I switch language from default to not default (from 'ka' to 'en'). I mean from this `localhost:3005/en/home` to this `localhost:3005/home`. Any idea how can I manage this? This is my next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    i18n: {
        localeDetection: false,
        locales: ['en', 'ka'],
        defaultLocale: 'ka'
    },
    eslint: {
        // Warning: This allows production builds to successfully complete even if
        // your project has ESLint errors.
        ignoreDuringBuilds: true
    }
}
```

Comment: Great question, I am stuck with the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I did, but i don't work on this project anymore and I cant remember the solution from my head :( sorry